# Incremental count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataset as below. and want to get count of C2 group by C1 as shown below.

```
C1  C2
a   1
a   2
a   3
a   4
a   5
b   1
b   2
b   3
b   4
b   5
b   6
c   6
c   7
```

Expected result below. Count of **b** should be the items not present in **a**. Same for **c** ie not present in **a** or **b**

```
a   5
b   1
c   1
```

is there any logic i can use in pandas to get this. other than iterating through the records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove duplicates on `'C2'` column and count the values that left on `'C1'`:

```
print(df.drop_duplicates('C2')['C1'].value_counts())
#  a    5
#  b    1
#  c    1
#  Name: C1, dtype: int64
```

The output will be a series. You can use `to_frame` if you want a dataframe:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('C2')['C1'].value_counts().to_frame()
print(df)
#     C1
#  a   5
#  b   1
#  c   1
```

**Caveat**

- `value_counts` sorts the output by default. In this case it doesn't make a difference, but you can pass `sort=False` so the lines (indexes) will stay in the same order as in the original dataframe.

Comment: This is really awsome !!.

Comment: Can i ask one more question along with this? How do i get exclusive C2s count for each C1?. In the above example a- 0 , b-0 , c-1